# how can I exclude collections when I get types from an assembly c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following method:

```
 public static Type[] GetAllClasses(this Assembly assembly)
 {
        var types= assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(x=>x.IsClass).OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToArray();

        return types;
 }
```

I would like to exclude all types that are collections .How can I do that?

When debugging I can see that collection have a baseType"List'1".How can I trap that and exclude those?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work...

```
var types= assembly.GetExportedTypes()
.Where(x=>x.IsClass && x.GetInterface("IEnumerable")==null)
.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
```

(Or use the more specific collection interfaces - IList or ICollection if you want to exclude those)

Comment: Just made amendment. DIdn't see you wanted to exclude collections.